# Запись данных в List в Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Как записывать данные в List в Thymeleaf? Выдает ошибку:
`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "registration" - line 39, col 28)`

Идея проста: 
Есть клиент и к нему нужно привентить 2 телефона. Пытаюсь добавить возможность считывать данные с html (post mapping у меня есть). Ошибка кроется где-то в Controller'e и в `th:value="*{phoneNumber[0].phoneNumber}"`

У меня есть сущность Customer:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Есть сущность PhoneNumbers:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "phoneNumber")
public class PhoneNumber {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "phone_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your phone number")
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

Мой контроллер (Уверен, первая ошибка кроется тут):

```java
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView registration(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        modelAndView.addObject("customer", customer);
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

registration.html:

```html
 <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="POST">
    <label>Имя
        <input type="text" th:field="*{customer.name}" name="name" th:placeholder="name">
    </label>
    <br>
    ...
    <h2>Телефон</h2>

    <label>Контактный телефон 1
        <input type="text" th:value="*{phoneNumber[0].phoneNumber}" name="phoneNumber" th:placeholder="phoneNumber">
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>Контактный телефон 2
        <input type="text" th:value="*{phoneNumber[1].phoneNumber}" name="phoneNumber" th:placeholder="phoneNumber">
    </label>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Завершить регистрацию">
</form>
```

Comment: В модель кладется только customer, а в шаблоне обращаешься к массиву phoneNumber. Попробуй так  {customer.phoneNumber[1].phoneNumber}

Comment: @zuzzz Все бы ничего... Но у меня вместо массива используется List

Comment: @Antonio112009, пользуйтесь на здоровье [итерацией](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается очень легко.

**Шаг 1:**

```java
customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
```

Эти строки нам нужны для добавления пустых объектов в `List`. Тут, логично, добавлено 2 пустых элемента. Если потребуется добавить больше 2-4 - лучше использовать `for-loop`.

**Шаг 1.5:**
У меня была ошибка, что я отдельно вызывал `PhoneNumber` от `Customer`, поэтому надо вызывать правильно вот так: `customer.phoneNumber...`

**Шаг 2**

```java
<input type="text" th:field="*{customer.phoneNumbers[0].phoneNumber}" name="phoneNumber" th:placeholder="phoneNumber">
```

При работе с `list`, [мы отображаем наши входные данные как свойства элементов списка, используя `th:field`](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list). Поэтому правильная запись будет: th:field="*{customer.phoneNumbers[0].phoneNumber}".

Стоит отметить, что при выборке объектов мы **не используем** `.get(i)`, а делаем как с array: `phoneNumbers[0]`.

Так же стоит отметить, что `name` должен иметь такое же название как и финальная переменная, вызванная в строке `th:field` - `name="phoneNumber"`.

Это все.